# google closure compiler error on external jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-closure

I'm getting a weird error using google closure compiler. I'm using externs to indicate a reference to jquery but it's not working. I know the picture is not too good but if you open it on a new tab, you'll see what I'm referring to.

It bugs on the .html() function but not the .text() function; in fact, the output code doesn't  rename the .text() function, it only renames the .html() function and it bugs.

How do you link jquery to closure compiler?

Thanks.

[image: google compiler]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your options are messed up.  It should start with a single block:

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// ...
// ...
// ==/ClosureCompiler==
```